# How to resume loading in PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am using `XAMPP` and `PHPMyAdmin` and I'm trying to load English `Wikipedia`. Since the file is so big (1.7GB), it take a lot of time. I'm wondering if there is any way to resume the loading process. I have no problem with TimeOut or something like that. The problem is that if my firefox crashes for any reason, the process must start from the scratch.

The part which says allow interrupt is already checked with a check mark. But the problem is that for such a big file that I am loading, it's really difficult to expect to be done without any interrupt. If the laptop is shut down or restarted or so, the process is repeated from the beginning. Is there any way to solve this problem?

In the meantime, I am using

> $cfg['UploadDir'] = 'upload';

and load the file from the upload directory on my computer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the file a SQL script, or csv, or something? can you split the file into lots of separate, smaller files?

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your comments. It's a single zip file. I also tried to split it. But since the file is too big (the zipped file is 1.7 GB and the unzipped version is 12GB), even splitting it into 50 parts didn't help. Each part took a lot of time which had the same problem. When split into 50 parts, one part was not finished after 8 hours and my firefox crashed for some other problems.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend against using phpMyAdmin for such a large file. You're going to be constrained by PHP/Apache resource limits for things such as execution time and memory used (or, apparently, some Firefox resource on the client side), to a degree that even if it works properly will have to be done in so many small chunks that it's just not ideal. Even using the UploadDir functionality, you're going to be limited in ways that make it non-ideal to import your file this way. I suggest using the command-line tool for importing a file of this size.

Secondly, if you're going to use phpMyAdmin anyway, it's better to uncompress the file and deal with the raw .sql. This is not intuitive, because of course you think the smaller filesize is better, but phpMyAdmin has to first uncompress the compressed file before it can begin working with it, which can cause problems such as the resource limits (or even running out of disk space). phpMyAdmin can pick up an aborted import, but if you're spending 95% of the execution time uncompressing the file each time, you're going to make very, very slow progress. Actually, I wonder if you're even getting the full file uncompressed on execution before PHP kills the process due to timeout.

phpMyAdmin can pick up execution part way through; you can select which line to begin the import from. If you restart your computer part way through the export, you can use this means to resume your partial import.